# Download file from Dropbox C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropbox-api

I'm trying to download a pdf file that I have in Dropbox, I need to save it into my local computer, any folder it can be `C:\Users\User\Desktop` for example. 
This is the code I've been working with:

```
  public void DownloadPdf()
        {

            DropboxClient client2 = new DropboxClient("cU5M-asdgfsdfsdfds3434435dfgfgvXoAMCFyOXH");
            string folder = "MyFolder";
            string file = "Test PDF.pdf";
            var response = client2.Files.DownloadAsync("/" + folder + "/" + file);         
        }
```

How can I save that file into my local drive? What do I need to do next? It doesn't throw any error but I'm not even sure that path is going into the pdf document in Dropbox. I'm using Dropbox.Api within ASP.net Core.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need to do is convert the content to a stream and download to your local path. You can do that like so

```
public void DownloadPdf(string localFilePath)
{
    DropboxClient client2 = new DropboxClient("cU5M-asdgfsdfsdfds3434435dfgfgvXoAMCFyOXH");
    string folder = "MyFolder";
    string file = "Test PDF.pdf";
    using (var response = await client.Files.DownloadAsync("/" + folder + "/" + file))
    {
        using (var fileStream = File.Create(localFilePath))
        {
            (await response.GetContentAsStreamAsync()).CopyTo(fileStream);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do  not do `.Result`, use another await. Using `.Result` will likely lead to a deadlock in the program. Using a `.ConfigureAwait(false)` on both awaits would not hurt either.

Comment: Also, you are not disposing the stream.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I'm getting a compile time error in this snippet: ` using (var fileStream = File.Created(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Notes"))` The error is: `CS0119 'ControllerBase.File(byte[], string)' is a method, which is not valid in the given context` .  I've tried to use it on this way before but I was crashed by that error, according to the error File refers to a method?? and once I put a point after `File` it doesn't shows `Create`, it shows `Created`, any idea?

Comment: You likely have a class or method called `File`, use `System.IO.File.Create(` instead.

Comment: It's working now!!