# Read Operation failed. Large Files Azure BlobUpload using only stream of DROPBOX api

Tags: c#, multithreading, dropbox-api, azure-blob-storage

The code below fails at : bodyreader.ReadToEnd()
 I want to download large files from DROPBPOX without saving it into my 
 memory/localdisk.
I am using Parallel.Forloop to download multiple files.

```
    public static DropboxClient dropboxClient;
    var response = await dropboxClient.Files.DownloadAsync(file[0]);
     var fileStream = await response.GetContentAsStreamAsync();

try { 
                container = obj.BloBHandle();
                table = obj.TableHandle();
                StreamReader bodyReader = new StreamReader(filepath);
                string bodyString = bodyReader.ReadToEnd();

                block = container.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);

                int blockSize = 4 * 1024 * 1024;  //256 kb
                int fileSize = bodyString.Length;
                //long fileSize = filepath.Length;


                //block count is the number of blocks + 1 for the last one
            int blockCount = (int)((float)fileSize / (float)blockSize) + 1;

            //List of block ids; the blocks will be committed in the order of this list 
            List<string> blockIDs = new List<string>();
            //starting block number - 1
            int blockNumber = 0;

                int bytesRead = 0; //number of bytes read so far

                long bytesLeft = fileSize; //number of bytes left to read and upload

                //do until all of the bytes are uploaded
                while (bytesLeft > 0)
                {
                    blockNumber++;
                    int bytesToRead;
                    if (bytesLeft >= blockSize)
                    {
                        //more than one block left, so put up another whole block
                        bytesToRead = blockSize;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //less than one block left, read the rest of it
                        bytesToRead = (int)bytesLeft;
                    }

                    //create a blockID from the block number, add it to the block ID list
                    //the block ID is a base64 string
                    string blockId =
                      Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("BlockId{0}",
                        blockNumber.ToString("0000000"))));
                    blockIDs.Add(blockId);
                    //set up new buffer with the right size, and read that many bytes into it 
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[bytesToRead];
                    filepath.Read(bytes, 0, bytesToRead);
                    //    Stream stream = new MemoryStream(bytesToRead);

                    //calculate the MD5 hash of the byte array
                    string blockHash = GetMD5HashFromStream(bytes);

                    //upload the block, provide the hash so Azure can verify it
                    block.PutBlock(blockId, new MemoryStream(bytes), blockHash);

                    //increment/decrement counters
                    bytesRead += bytesToRead;
                    bytesLeft -= bytesToRead;
                }

                //commit the blocks
                block.PutBlockList(blockIDs);



            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
```

then we tried without blocks just UploadFromStream

Like this

```
   block = container.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);      
   block.UploadFromStream(stream);
```

With this for small files it is uploading Successfully & for large files upto 50% of the file  it is uploading later we are getting exception like

> request was aborted request was cancelled

Answer (score 0):

> The code below fails at : bodyreader.ReadToEnd() I want to download large files from DROPBPOX without saving it into my memory/localdisk.

For temporarily saving large file to local disk, you could follow this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39881803/download-file-from-dropbox-c-sharp), then you could use `CloudBlockBlob.UploadFromFile` and specify the `BlobRequestOptions`, then the client SDK would break large file into blocks and automatically upload each block in parallel for you. You could follow this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41054784/uploading-files-to-azure-blob-storage-taking-more-time-for-larger-files/41098868#41098868) and this [blog](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/cloud/platform-as-a-service/azure-blob-storage-part-4-uploading-large-blobs/) about **Uploading a file using the .NET Storage SDK**.

For temporarily saving large file to memory, I assumed that you could try to specify `BlobRequestOptions` parameter for `UploadFromStream` method and increase the limitation (e.g. [BlobRequestOptions.ParallelOperationThreadCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.blobrequestoptions.paralleloperationthreadcount?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_BlobRequestOptions_ParallelOperationThreadCount),[BlobRequestOptions.ServerTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.blobrequestoptions.servertimeout?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_BlobRequestOptions_ServerTimeout),etc.) to narrow this issue.